# Computing $\int\sqrt{x^2 - 25} \,\mathrm d x$. Where am I wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I wondering where I'm wrong...

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

Thanks

Comment: Your answer should be something about $x$, not $\theta$.  But you are correct, the answer is wrong.  (Differentiate to see if you get the desired integrand).  So... take a line about half-way down, see if that is right.  This will tell you whether your mistake is before or after that point.

Comment: Now, you know how to check whether the answer is correct, so do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. You did not back substitute $\sec\theta = x/5$, $\tan\theta = \sqrt{x^2-25}/5$.
2. The factor of 12.5 in front of the logarithm in the last line appears to have escaped.

Otherwise, this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should be of some help to you:

https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sqrt%28x%5E2%20-%2025%29

Also, don't forget that your answer should be in terms of $x$, not $\theta$. You need to substitute back in.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
I &=\int dx\sqrt{x^2-25} \\
&= \int d\theta\tan\theta\sec\theta\sqrt{25\sec^2(\theta)-25} \\
&=5\int d\theta \tan^2\theta\sec\theta \\
&=5\int d\theta\; \frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos^3\theta} \\
&=5\int d\theta (\sec^3\theta ) + 5\int d\theta (\sec\theta) \\
&=5(J+K) \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
K&=\int d\theta \sec\theta \\
&=\int d\theta \left(\frac{\sec\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}\right) \\
u&=\sec\theta+\tan\theta \\
K&= \int du \,\frac{1}{u} \\
&= \ln |u| \\
&= \ln |\sec\theta+\tan\theta|
\end{align}
\begin{align}
J&=\tan\theta\sec\theta-\int d\theta (\tan^2\theta\sec\theta) \\
&=\tan\theta\sec\theta - \int d\theta(\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta) \\
&=\tan\theta\sec\theta-J+K \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\tan\theta\sec\theta+\frac{1}{2}K \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\tan\theta\sec\theta + \frac{1}{2}\ln |\sec\theta+\tan\theta|
\end{align}
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{5}{2}\tan\theta\sec\theta + \frac{15}{2}\ln |\sec\theta+\tan\theta| \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{x\sqrt{x^2-25}}{5}+\frac{15}{2}\ln \left|\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-25}}{5}\right|
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use the so called Euler subsitution:
$$\sqrt{x^2-25}=t+x$$